# When will official widgets for YUI 3 come?

Tags: yui

I don't just understand their logic. The YUI site says that the full suite of widgets and utilities for YUI 3 will come in 2010. But they've not released it yet. What do you think? Should I wait or go in for something like jQuery UI. And, yes, I don't want to use YUI 2...

Comment: You should ask the authors of that site.

Comment: http://alloy.liferay.com/demos.php

All of these use YUI 3. There is a lot in the YUI 3 Gallery as well: http://yuilibrary.com/gallery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YUI3 widgets have started to appear, and more are on the way.

They've also made it [very easy](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/03/11/yui-2-in-3-coming-soon/) to use YUI2 widgets within YUI3 (blog post talks about the future, but that functionality is released now). Is there a specific one you're missing?

Answer (score 0):

Man, I've been using JQuery for years, YUI2, YUI3, and Dojo.. YUI2 is the worst of all in terms of complicated syntax, lack of features, and worst-of-all, lack of documentation. Yui3 is a lot better but still lacks. Try JQuery with JQuery UI.. the documentation is awesome; the UI theme roller is amazing.